# Export Audience Overview data for a specific Segment, from Google Analytics

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I know how to export Audience Overview data for a specific Segment from Google Analytics website:

- Go to https://analytics.google.com, then *Reports > Audience > Overview*
- Click *+ Add segment*, choose the relevant segment
- Select the date range, then *Apply*
- Click the top right button *Export > Excel XLSX*, then open the downloaded file with Excel and go in the second sheet named `Dataset1`, get the data from the second column `Users`

**But how to get the number of users for a specific Segment in a specific date range automatically from Python code, instead of using the website / GUI?**

Or ss it possible to do it with a custom URL? e.g.

```
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/report/visitors-
overview/<<<<account>>>>/_u.date00=20180611&_u.date01=20180712&overview-
graphOptions.selected=analytics.nthDay&_.useg=<<<<segment>>>>/
```

and add a parameter to this URL to automatically download the data?

Comment: If your using the Google analytics api please edit your question and include your code.   And describe any issues you are having with your code.

Comment: If you haven't yet tried any code, now's the time. Note that if you are working within Google Apps Script, its ["advanced service" client library for `Analytics`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analytics) uses an older API version (v3), while a 3rd party program can use v4. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference

Comment: @Basj that appears to just select sessions for a profile in for the last week.   Your not going to see [segments](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#segments) until you add it to the request.   you will have better luck with this switching to the newest version of the api as well

Comment: If your going to use v3 you can start here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#segment I already gave you a link for v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, here are the steps to access Google Analytics data via Python (more details [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py)):

- `pip install google-api-python-client oauth2client`
- create a `Service account` [here](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts)

  [image]
- download its JSON key file (named `keyfile.json` after),
- add the service account email address `<identifier>@<projectid>.iam.gserviceaccount.com` to the Google Analytics Account, in *Admin > User management*.
- enable the Analytics API here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics.googleapis.com/overview?project=...

then use this code (in the case you already know the profile ID, here 152373812, and the ID of the Custom Segment, here 7yMBa3f7RimTf2SFtRQaRh):

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

key_file = 'keyfile.json'
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(key_file, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'])
service = build(serviceName='analytics', version='v3', credentials=credentials)
results = service.data().ga().get(ids='ga:152373812', start_date='7daysAgo', end_date='today', metrics='ga:users', segment='gaid::7yMBa3f7RimTf2SFtRQaRh', dimensions='ga:date').execute()

print 'View (Profile):', results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')
print 'Users of each day:', results.get('rows')
```

---

Here is some code to get the informations about properties, profiles, segments, etc. associated to a Google Analytics account, useful for example to get the Profile ID and Custom Segment ID mentioned before:

```
from pprint import pprint
properties = service.management().webproperties().list(accountId=account).execute().get('items')
print 'PROPERTIES'
pprint(properties)

profiles = service.management().profiles().list(accountId=account, webPropertyId=properties[0].get('id')).execute().get('items')
print 'PROFILES'
pprint(profiles)

segments = service.management().segments().list().execute().get('items')
print 'SEGMENTS'
pprint(segments)
```

---

Very important: if you want a Custom Segment to be displayed in the `service.management().segments()` list, you need to edit the *Segment availability* to *Collaborators and I can apply/edit Segment in this View*. (If you don't do this, you will only see default segments via API but not custom ones!). More informations about this [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6121378?hl=en&ref_topic=3123779) ("Set segment availability") and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31620673/1422096).

[image]

Comment: is this an answer? or should it be an edit on your question.   I am still not seeing anything with regard to selecting segments.  And now you have gone over to the management api which still has nothing to do with selecting segments.

Comment: I'm still unable to get the informations for a specific segment.  <--- you haven't tried yet.

Comment: @DaImTo: I edited to add these informations. Phew, it was a long journey, especially the last remark in the answer (during a long time, I couldn't see the Custom Segments ;))!